# Core Reporting API - Ignore URL params and "group by"

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am using **Google Core Reporting API** to pull data from **Google Analytics**.

The query I am currently using is:

```
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    'today',
    'today',
    'ga:pageviews',
    array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results' => 300
    )
);
```

The problem with this query is that the same page is returned several times if it comes with different parameters.

- /friendly/url
- /friendly/url?a=1
- /friendly/url?a=1&b=2

I would like to ignore the parameters and receive an aggregated data of **/friendly/url** page.

I could not find how to achieve this using Google's docs.
Can somebody help please?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The value of 'ga:pagePath' is the

> [ga:pagePath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) A page on your website specified by path and/or query
>   parameters. Use in conjunction with hostname to get the full URL of
>   the page.

As you can see by the documentation it includes the Path and the query

- /friendly/url
- /friendly/url?a=1
- /friendly/url?a=1&b=2

your best bet if you want to return those with out the query would be to add a filter to your [request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters)

probably something like

```
filters=ga:pagePath%3D%3D/friendly/url
```

Just remember the number returned by 'ga:pageviews' will only contain that one url.  I recommend testing the filter and the results in the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

**Update Playing:**

Ok what you are trying to do is interesting so I thought I would play with it a little.

On my website I have s for search. ga:pagepath is giving me some lovely stuff like this.

- /?s= 1
- /?s=400 1
- /?s=Access+denied 1
- /?s=Analytics+Multi-Channel
- /?s=Google+Calendar+API+with+.net+–+Service+Account

The request I used

```
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=2016-01-31&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&max-results=1000
```

What if I want the total number of times someone has used search.

I add a filter to the request `ga:pagepath=@/?s=` and remove the ga:pagepath dimension.   then ga:users is a count of what was returned by the filter.

This isn't really adding a group by its more like adding a where clause, but I think its close.

```
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=2016-01-31&metrics=ga%3Ausers&filters=ga%3Apagepath%3D%40%2F%3Fs%3D&max-results=1000
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the API to return a single row with the consolidated result for "/friendly/url". I don't think this is possible ( in a query that contains the page path) without postprocessing the API results.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, you are right, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I was hoping that the op would realize that it wasn't possible  what he wanted to do. I don't like posting "nope you cant do that."   I was hoping that this a work around for his problem would help.   I can delete it if you don't get any value from the information.

Comment: @EikePierstorff  What if he added the filter Contains substring and removes the 'ga:pagePath' dimension.  Wouldn't it return a total for them all.   Need to go test that idea :)

Answer (score 1):

ga:pagePath contains the url including its parameters.

uses ga:pagePath to filter the results that you need

but set  ga:pagePathLevel{1,2,3,4} as dimension.

the result will be aggregated correctly!

By

Comment: ga:pagePathLevel1 doesn't resolve the issue with query params.